# Got 4 answers for logarithm question but calculator only gives 2

Tags: logarithms

Logarithm question is $\log_9(\sqrt[3]{(x^2-1)^2}) = \frac{1}{3}$

When I solved the question I rewrote the question as $\sqrt[3]{9} = \sqrt[3]{(x^2-1)^2}$, canceled the
cube roots and then took the square root of both sides to get $x^2-1 = \pm3$ and then getting $x^2 = 4, x^2 = -2$, giving the solutions of $2, -2, \sqrt{2}i, -\sqrt{2}i,$ however after putting the question into online calculators like wolfram alpha, they only gave the solutions of $2, -2.$

Answer (score 1):

Many calculators only know how to calculate real solutions. When I typed your formula into Wolfram Alpha (using `cbrt` to indicate cube root) it said:

> assuming "cbrt" is the real-valued root

I selected the option to "Use the principal root instead" and it gave me all four answers as expected.

At first, I thought it had to do with $\log$ operating on real numbers; however, this is **not** correct because even if $x$ is complex, $x^2-1$ is $3$ when $x=2,-2$ and $-3$ when $x=i\sqrt2,-i\sqrt2$ so $(x^2-1)^2$ is always $9$ so the value under the cube root is always real anyway and so there is a real root to $\log$.

So, I think the issue is just with the calculator itself. I don't know how you typed it into Wolfram Alpha, but I got an option to use the principal root and it made the two complex solutions appear as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that $\log_a(x)$ with $a>0\land a\neq1$ is a function of real number. This meams that letting $f(x)=\log_a(x)$:
$$f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$$
Or, in other words, $\mathbb{R}$ is the domain and codomai of $\log_a(x)$. You can define $\log$ function in complex numbers, but it's another tool. So, WolpramAlpha is right, your equation:
$$\log_9(\sqrt[3]{x^2-1})=\frac{1}{3}$$
has only two solutions: $x_1=2 \lor x_2=-2$.

Here a basic rule: when you are trying to solve this type of equation, always look carefully to the domain that is in this case:
$$x\in (-\infty, -1) \cup(1, +\infty)$$

Comment: Even if $x$ is complex, in the case of $i\sqrt2$, $x^2=-2$ so $x^2-1=-3$ so $(x^2-1)^2=9$ and so $\log\left(\sqrt[3]{(x^2-1)^2}\right)$ should work because there is a real root of $\sqrt[3]{9}$ which works under $\log$, wouldn't it?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino: we are working with real number (cube root or logarithm do not matter). All function are of the type: $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If OP is getting complex numbers in their answer and are asking about it, clearly they aren't working with everything being real. Even with the real defn of logarithm _and_ cube root it _still_ doesn't explain why $x$ itself can't be complex.

Comment: I understood that the domain of the log function needs to be real numbers but the x in the answers that is complex isn't the input of the log function but is just inside the input and you will get the cube root of 9 as the input as hyper-neutrino said